# How to insert elements into a multidimensional vector of unique pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a Turn class with a _rounds private member. _rounds is a bidimensional std vector of std unique pointers to another class called Animation:

**Turn.h**

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animation>>> _rounds;
```

**Animation.h**

```
class Animation
{
public:
    enum Type
    {
        MOVE,
        ATTACK,
        DIE,
        FADEOUT,
        MAX_TYPES
    };

//Constructors
Animation();        
Animation(Creature* creature, Animation::Type type, GameManager* gameManager, const std::function<void()> callback = nullptr);

//Getters   
const int& getOriginRowClipsIndex() { return _originRowClipsIndex; }
bool& getFinished() { return _finished; }
Type& getType() { return _type; }
Creature& getCreature() { return *_creature; }

//Setters       
void setOriginRowClipsIndex(int originRowClipsIndex) { _originRowClipsIndex = originRowClipsIndex; }

void animate(); 
void reset();
SDL_Rect* getClip(int index) {      
    return &_clips[index];      
}

private:
    GameManager* _gameManager;
    Creature * _creature;
    bool _finished;
    unsigned int _clipIndex;
    int _frequency;
    int _originRowClipsIndex; //Origin index of anim clips.     
    std::vector<SDL_Rect> _clips;   
    Type _type; 
    std::function<void()> _callback;
};
#endif
```

I dynamically allocate the Animations from various points of my code and try to add them to Turn _rounds with a Turn public method called addAnimation like this:

```
auto animation = std::make_unique<Animation>(this, Animation::Type::MOVE, _gameManager);            
turn.addAnimation(std::move(animation)); //Use move to make addAnimation take ownership of the animation.
```

Then the Turn addAnimation() method tries to add the Animations to its member _rounds as follows:

**Turn.cpp**

```
void Turn::addAnimation(std::unique_ptr<Animation> animation)
{   
unsigned int roundIndex;

//Set animating to true when the first animation is added to the first animation round. TODO: Move this elsewhere.
if (_rounds.size() == 0)
    _animating = true;

if (animation->getType() == Animation::MOVE) { //All move animations go on first round.
    roundIndex = 0;
    if (animation->getCreature().isPlayer()) //Set _playerMoves to be able to set monster attacks on the correct round index.
    {
        _playerMoves = true;
    }
}else if (animation->getType() == Animation::ATTACK) 
{
    roundIndex = _playerMoves ? _nAttacks + 1 : _nAttacks;
    _nAttacks++; //Increment number of attacks.     
}
else
{
    roundIndex = _rounds.size();
}

//Check if the wanted round index already exists and create if not.
if (roundIndex >= _rounds.size()) {
    //_rounds.push_back({});
    _rounds.resize(_rounds.size() + 1);
}

//Add animation to animations vector.
_rounds[roundIndex].push_back(std::move(animation));
}
```

However I am getting an error saying that I am trying to **reference a deleted function** as if I was trying to use the deleted copy constructor or something.

```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: Roguelike, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Turn.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0(637): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Animation
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\memory(1435): note: see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Animation
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0(755): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct<_Objty,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>&>(_Objty *,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>,
1>              _Objty=std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0(755): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct<_Objty,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>&>(_Objty *,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>,
1>              _Objty=std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0(894): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>&>(std::allocator<_Ty> &,_Objty *,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>>,
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>,
1>              _Objty=std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0(893): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>&>(std::allocator<_Ty> &,_Objty *,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>>,
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>,
1>              _Objty=std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(1286): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>>::construct<std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>&>(_Ty *,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(1285): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>>::construct<std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>&>(_Ty *,std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<Animation>>
1>          ]
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(1278): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>::push_back(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Animation
1>          ]
1>  c:\cpp\roguelike\roguelike\turn.cpp(44): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>::push_back(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Animation
1>          ]
1>  c:\cpp\roguelike\roguelike\turn.cpp(44): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animation,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Animation
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The only point of my code that appears at the end of the long chain of template errors is at the push_back to the unique pointers vector of addAnimation.

If I try to compile a simplified case I have no problem even adding custom constructors to Animation class:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Animation
{
    int _animation_value;
public:
    Animation() {};
    Animation(int animation_value)
        : _animation_value(animation_value)
    {}
};

class Turn
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animation>>> _rounds;
public:
    void addAnimation(std::unique_ptr<Animation> round)
    {
        _rounds.resize(_rounds.size() + 1);
        _rounds[0].push_back(std::move(round));
    }
};

class Other
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        auto x = std::make_unique<Animation>(7);
        Turn turn;
        turn.addAnimation(std::move(x));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Other other;
    other.foo();        
    return 0;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you post `Turn` code?

Comment: Please post the actual error message.  Important information is often lost when paraphrasing.  A [mcve] wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @Corristo rounds is a vector of vectors, round[x] is a vector of pointers, i. e. everything fine...

Comment: You *are* trying to use "the deleted copy constructor or something", through `push_back`.

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah, I had already noticed my mistake and deleted the comment :)

Comment: @molbdnilo why is he using the copy constructor? std::vector::push_back(T&& value) is a valid overload. Why does the implementation fall back to copying the value?

Comment: I posted the full addAnimation method and the full error report. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is turn.cpp line 44?

Comment: turn.cpp line 44 is _rounds[roundIndex].push_back(std::move(animation));

Comment: Trying to reproduce with GCC, using `int` instead of `Animation`, but failing...

Comment: Trying to reproduce with VisualStudio2015, using `int` instead of `Animation`, but also failing...

Comment: Actually I can't either reproduce it on an empty project neither with int or a dummy class (VS 2015). Any advices on how to debug it?

Comment: @acraig5075 I disagree, You just need to call `rounds.push_back(std::move(first));`

Comment: @HarleyFuagras Changing `push_back` to `emplace_back` solves this issue?

Comment: If you meant _rounds[roundIndex].emplace_back(std::move(animation)); No, it does not solve it.

Comment: Actually I am not able to do that. I can't reproduce the error on an empty and simplified project. Any advices on debugging it?

Comment: @HarleyFuagras Can you share Animation class code? And any classes it derives from?

Comment: Animation.h added. In the meantime I realized that within addAnimation I am not capable of creating a new bidimensional vector of Animations and fill it with new unique pointers to animations, but I can do the same with other classes of the project. So I can imagine it has something to do with Animation class, but I don't know what.

Comment: Save your project state.  Back it up.  Now start deleting code.  Rebuild after each delete to confirm **the error still happens**.  Backup project when you confirm it still happens, then repeat and delete more code.  The first round is easy: reduce `addAnimation` to the one line the error is coming from.  Rebuild.  Still get error?  Continue, make backup, maybe delete entire files from project.  Don't get error?  Return to last backup and delete code elsewhere.  You do not care about runtime.  You do not care about linker errors.  You just want to reproduce the same build error in a [mcve]

Comment: A minimal example you are aiming for is **one** file with less than 20 lines of code in it.  Ideally with a **command line** call to cl.exe with known, minimal, command line arguments.  But you don't skip to that; you reduce to that ensuring that you do not lose the error as you reduce.  Along the way you may discover the cause, or find it requires two files (!), or something, but that is what you aim for.

Comment: Ok, fiddling around I found the problem. On Turn constructor I was initializing rounds vector with `_rounds = {};`. Removing that line fixes the problem but I don't quite understand why.

Answer (score 1):

are you copying your turn class anywhere in the code? because, as stated in the comments, there seems to be no error in the addAnimation function itself. so maybe you generate some code where the whole turn class gets copied and so the vector of vectors of unique pointers wants to make a copy?

Comment: The only similar thing I can find is that Turn objects are also a members of another class, and that class has a getter method for the turn: `Turn& getTurn() { return _turn; }` Maybe I should use shared_ptr instead of unique_ptr?

Comment: 1. sure if you use shared_pointers, the problem will go away. but that's not what we/you want. shared_pointers are not as lightweight as unique_pointers and i recommend using unique_pointers, if they really represent what you got. (if you want to share your instances, they go ahead and use shared_ptr of course)




2. your getTurn method seems to be fine, since you dont copy your turn instance. but as soon as you copy your turn instance and you dont write your own copy routines, the compiler wants to copy the vector. and since you cant copy the unique_ptr you can get the error message.

Comment: @HarleyFuagras "Ok, fiddling around I found the problem. On Turn constructor I was initializing rounds vector with _rounds = {};. Removing that line fixes the problem but I don't quite understand why." i may be wrong, but i guess its because you are creating an empty vector of uniquepointers with help of an initializer_list and this list will get copied in the assignment. even if the list is empty, the code for the copy has to be compileable (just a guess. but it would make sense)